# WebSockets listening on UNIX domain socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, nginx, websocket

Is it possible to setup a WebSockets server behind an nginx server which handles connections on a UNIX domain socket?

I currently have several WebSocket server instances on the same machine and have the problem of port sharing. All instances must be allocated a unique port. I want to avoid that and instead communicate between nginx and the WebSockets backend using UNIX domain sockets.

The WebSockets library I'm using is ws (https://github.com/einaros/ws)

I currently create my server like this:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({host: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080});
```

Answer (score 9):

Server side:

```
var http = require('http');
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var server = http.createServer()
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server : server});
server.listen('/tmp/server.sock')
```

Client side:

```
var ws = require('ws');
var client = new ws("ws+unix:///tmp/server.sock")
client.send('hello')
```

Comment: https://github.com/taigaio/taiga-events (see index.coffee) does not use a `server.listen` call and therefore i don't understand how to inject the socket. any idea on that?

Comment: How do i connect to .sock via client side (html) to update/send updates from user interface

Comment: @mr.work you can't connect to unix socket from browser, you need to use reverse-proxy so your browser connects to proxy and proxy forwards the request to unix socket.

Comment: If you get EADDRINUSE, try fs.unlinkSync('/tmp/server.sock')