# C# WebSockets listening on UNIX domain socket?

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, ipc, unix-socket

I have a few processes on one computer or in a network. Processes on .Net core, python, go. I need ipc. I am going to use UnixDomainSocket on a local machine. Tcp on a local network.

I found middleware Asp.net core for WebSocket,  and third-party solutions (ZeroMQ, [NetCoreServer](https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer)) on communication. But its are big and don't allow UnixDomainSocket.

How create WSSocket use in background UnixDomainSocket on C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to a Unix Domain Socket in .NET Core in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195290/how-to-connect-to-a-unix-domain-socket-in-net-core-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I need change transport for WebSocket. WebSocket is wrap on socket. In node.js I can change transport level. Listenining unixsocket  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930293/websockets-listening-on-unix-domain-socket